# CakePHP Bypass Auth component

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to bypass the Auth component and be logged in as an administrator? I want to test a plugin I downloaded and it requires you to be logged in using the Auth component as admin but I don't want to setup a users table etc.

Comment: Since by default Cake has no specific notion of an admin user, or users in general, it sounds like this plugin very specifically depends on the AuthComponent and an appropriately set up user model that handles admins. That, or you're misunderstanding the instructions.

Comment: My assumption would be that it requires you to be admin to access the admin views but that's about it I think, it's for the Paypal IPN plugin.

Comment: If you're talking about [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/webtechnick/2009/08/11/paypal-ipn-instant-payment-notification-plugin-complete-with-paypalhelper), it just seems to default to admin_ prefixed routes for the admin tasks. That does not really have anything to do with the AuthComponent, the author probably just assumes you're protecting your admin_ actions with it. If you're not, it shouldn't matter. Have you tried? Does or doesn't it work?

Comment: Looks like this plugin is all over the place, I set up the user table and routes but errors everywhere, love open source :( LOL.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass authentication by using the following code in your beforeFilter() of your controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}
```

If you want to toggle only specific actions:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('admin_index', 'admin_view');
}
```

Now, you won't have to log in to access these pages. :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Wildcards like "admin_*" can't be used. You can use only "*" (which will work in your case). You can also enlist everything, like 'admin_index', 'admin_view', etc.